# Custom ribbon searching for ActiveWorkbook sub/functions instead of linked workbook

Tags: excel, vba

There are two files named `file_1.xlsm` and `files_2.xlsm`. Both have a `Module1.bas` with the same source code.
I've created a customized ribbon with a button that links a macro stored inside `Module1.bas` of `file_1.xlsm`. I'm trying to use the same button to load macro stored inside `ActiveWorkbook` actually, instead of the linked one.
Basically I need to link something like `ActiveWorkbook.Module1.bas` instead of `file_1.Module1.bas`, but I do not know how to achieve that.

I've tried to link ThisWorkbook but - of course - links to original file.

Comment: Such a pseudo linking does not exist, I am afraid... The Ribbon controls are triggered only in the workbook which created the custom Ribbon. But, if you want that, even if I cannot understand why necessary, you can easily call a macro from another workbook using `Application.Run`... You can make such a call from the `Sub` called by the button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I tried explaining in my comment above, you cannot 'link' any module/sub to a Ribbon control calling from another workbook. But, if you really need/want that, at least, for the sake of seeing it working, you can call the respective sub in the next circumstances:

```
Sub callTheSubInTheActiveWorkbook()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
      If ActiveWorkbook name = "file2.xlsm" then
        Application.Run "'" & wb.name & "'!Module1.MySub"
        Exit Sub
      End If
   Else
        'run the code here...
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ok thanks, unfortunately I need to give up because I do need a simple way to link my macro for my collegues. Thanks by the way, I close the question. I'll try something else, even if it's not as cool as that.

Comment: @Dovatti You **missed the point** in your question... In order to do that, transform the workbook in an add-in, make it self-installable and distribute it to your colleagues.